# Why space is [not] ignored in macro arguments?

Tags: tex-core

Test 1 prints *SPACE IGNORED*. From this we conclude that space from `\s` is ignored while argument scanning.
Test 2 differs from test 1, that * is appended to parameter list.
If space is ignored while argument scanning, then #1 should be empty.
But test 2 prints *SPACE*.
Why test 1 and test 2 are inconsistent? Which one works properly?
Where is this explained in TeXbook?

Test 1:

```
\def\a{*}
\def\x#1{\expandafter\xx\the#1}
\def\xx#1{\def\next{#1}\ifx\next\space\message{SPACE}\fi\ifx\next\a\message{SPACE IGNORED}\fi}
\newtoks\s \s={ } \x\s*
\bye
```

Test 2:

```
\def\a{*}
\def\x#1{\expandafter\xx\the#1}
\def\xx#1*{\def\next{#1}\ifx\next\space\message{SPACE}\fi\ifx\next\a\message{SPACE IGNORED}\fi}
\newtoks\s \s={ } \x\s*
\bye
```

Comment: an undelimited argument is a brace group or a single non space token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See page 201 of the TeXbook (near the bottom):

> After you have said ‘`\def\row#1#2{...}`’, you are allowed to put spaces between the arguments (e.g., ‘`\row x n`’), because TeX
> doesn’t use single spaces as undelimited arguments.

TeX ignores space tokens when looking for an undelimited argument, but it doesn't when looking for a delimited argument.

This is the big difference in the two cases, which we can unify in a single input file

```
\newtoks\s \s={ }

\def\a{*}

\def\x#1{\expandafter\xx\the#1}
\def\xx#1{\def\next{#1}\ifx\next\space\message{SPACE}\fi\ifx\next\a\message{SPACE IGNORED}\fi}

\def\y#1{\expandafter\yy\the#1}
\def\yy#1*{\def\next{#1}\ifx\next\space\message{SPACE}\fi\ifx\next\a\message{SPACE IGNORED}\fi}

\x\s*

\y\s*

\bye
```

In the console we'll see

```
SPACE IGNORED SPACE
```

and, as said, the difference is that the argument to `\xx` is undelimited, whereas the argument to `\yy` is delimited.

Let's follow expansions and assignments. A space token will be denoted by `•`:

```
\x\s*
\expandafter\xx\the\s*
\xx•*
```

In this case the argument to `\xx` is `*` and we see that the last line becomes

```
\def\next{*}\ifx\next\space\message{SPACE}\fi\ifx\next\a\message{SPACE IGNORED}\fi
```

and we rightly get `SPACE IGNORED`.

In the second case we get

```
\y\s*
\expandafter\yy\the\s*
\yy•*
```

and, according to the definition, the argument to `\yy` is `•`, making `\next` equivalent to `\space`.

I hope you're not confused with the fact that TeX ignores spaces after control words ***during tokenization***: it's a completely different business that happens well before TeX starts interpreting the input.